# Recognize new elements added to DOM after AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, dom

I am trying to display a new div element added to the DOM via AJAX.

So, via AJAX/PHP I added dynamically some new buttons

```
<button type="button" id="viewPP_'.$index.'" onclick="viewPP('.index.')">View</button>
```

And also added dynamically some new hidden divs

```
<div id="viewPP_'.$index.'" style="display: none;">
```

In my main page I have a JS function (before the $(document).ready) to show/hide the div

```
function viewPP(i){
    
var obj = "viewPP_"+i;
    
document.getElementById(obj).style.display = "block";
//$(obj).toggle();

}
```

If I use `document.getElementBy...` , nothing happens. (no error, just do nothing)

If I use `$(obj)`, nothing happens (no error, just do nothing)

I can understand new elements added to the DOM after the page is loaded are not recognized by JQuery, but can't find the way to make it work.

How can I do that??

Comment: How did you add the elements to the DOM?

Comment: Maybe you need to run your function after the DOM is loaded, that is inside a `$(document).ready(handler)`? https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: re-call `viewPP(i)`after Ajax success

Comment: Please answer yourself in the answer section only. No answers in the question please. Accept your answer once you have written it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed the buttons and divs had the same id, so I fixed them and now work.

Here's the working code, hope it helps someone in the future.

Thanks everyone for your help!

JS

```
function viewPP(i){   
  var obj = "#dataPP_"+i;
  $(obj).toggle();
} 

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
       ...
    });
});
```

PHP Response to AJAX Request

```
print '<button type="button" id="viewPP_'.$index.'" onclick="viewPP('.index.')">View</button>';

print '<div id="dataPP_'.$index.'" style="display: none;"></div>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove that #, when declaring obj. When you are using getElementById method, you just need to specify id, without #, as you would use in CSS or querySelector method.

```
function viewPP(i){
    
var obj = "viewPP_"+i;
    
document.getElementById(obj).style.display = "block"

}
```

If this is not it, there is something going on with loading these elements...

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be that, you can add a fix dpm element which can act as parent dom element for your dynamic dom element.
By this approach you can fetch child nodes of fixed dom parent node.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the JS code gets unbinded after the DOM is updated.You need to reinitialize the code after success as shown below

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: Urls.showMinicart,
    success: function (minCartData) {
        yourFunction();
    }
```

This will reinitialize your required JS code and this should work!